# IPage server side issue preventing PHP.ini from updating/PHP from showing

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

So I've had a few problems getting PHP to run on my iPage hosting. It turns out there was a problem on their end getting the session.save_path to actually save in the php.ini. I put in a support ticket and they sent me this:

> "We are sorry for the inconvenience caused to you. We have verified
>   your issue and the issue is with the design. Due to this reason,
>   session.save_pass is set as '4;/hermes/phpsession' in php.ini file or
>   it doesn't take updates. However, this does not affect your website in
>   any way. PHP session functionality should work fine without any issues
>   with this session path. "

So does this mean that I now have to create a separate directory and work around this location? I'm getting pretty frustrated because from what I understood about cpanel hosting, php "just ran" and at the moment it just displays the code. I've found a few posts here with others who had similar issues, but they all referenced changing the session.save_path, but as you can see I cant do that, and the knowledge base on iPage is a mess.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are literally hundreds of thousands of shared hosting providers, no need to persist with a crappy one.

Answer (score 0):

True. In iPage shared hosting, it is not possible to update session path in the php.ini file but the session functionality is expected to work as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to change the **session.save_path** but I did not work, So I have to contact there customer service  and they tell me that ***"It is not possible to edit the session path under php.ini"***.

All what I can do is define the session path in you PHP file by the following codes:

```
session_save_path('/your/home/directory/path/cgi-bin/tmp');
```

Put this in each php file and **before session_start()** command.